# JPA Mappings (OneToMany, ManyToOne)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mapping, cascade

Sale Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Data
public class Sale {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    @Column(name = "sale_price")
    BigDecimal salePrice;
    @Column(name = "sale_time")
    LocalDateTime saleTime;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<SaleItem> saleItems;
}
```

SaleItem Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale_item")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Data
public class SaleItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Product product;
    int quantity;
    BigDecimal price;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sale_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Sale sale;
}
```

Deleting saleItem from sale_item table

```
Sale sale=repo.findById(saleId).
orElseThrow(()->new NoSuchElementException("There is no sale with the id"));
SaleItem theSaleItem=sale.getSaleItems().stream().filter
(saleItem->saleItem.getProduct().getBarcode().equals(barcode)).findFirst().get();
saleItemRepo.delete(theSaleItem);
```

SQL codes

```
Hibernate: select si1_0.id,si1_0.price,p1_0.id,p1_0.barcode,p1_0.category,p1_0.price,p1_0.name,p1_0.quantity,si1_0.quantity,s1_0.id,s1_0.sale_price,s1_0.sale_time from sale_item si1_0 left join product p1_0 on p1_0.id=si1_0.product_id left join sale s1_0 on s1_0.id=si1_0.sale_id where si1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select si1_0.sale_id,si1_0.id,si1_0.price,p1_0.id,p1_0.barcode,p1_0.category,p1_0.price,p1_0.name,p1_0.quantity,si1_0.quantity from sale_item si1_0 left join product p1_0 on p1_0.id=si1_0.product_id where si1_0.sale_id=?
Hibernate: select si1_0.id,si1_0.price,p1_0.id,p1_0.barcode,p1_0.category,p1_0.price,p1_0.name,p1_0.quantity,si1_0.quantity,s1_0.id,s1_0.sale_price,s1_0.sale_time from sale_item si1_0 left join product p1_0 on p1_0.id=si1_0.product_id left join sale s1_0 on s1_0.id=si1_0.sale_id where si1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select si1_0.sale_id,si1_0.id,si1_0.price,p1_0.id,p1_0.barcode,p1_0.category,p1_0.price,p1_0.name,p1_0.quantity,si1_0.quantity from sale_item si1_0 left join product p1_0 on p1_0.id=si1_0.product_id where si1_0.sale_id=?
Hibernate: delete from sale_item where id=?
Hibernate: delete from sale_item where id=?
Hibernate: delete from sale_item where id=?
Hibernate: delete from sale_item where id=?
Hibernate: delete from sale where id=?
```

I have 'sale' and 'sale_item' tables as you see
Cascade types 'ALL' in mappings
When I save sale it saves sale_items as I want
But when I want to delete specific sale_item it deletes all saleItems which have same sale_id and related sale
For example in sale table I have a sale that id = 2 and in sale_item table I have 3 saleItems that ids are 1,2,3 respectively. When I delete saleItem that id = 1, It automatically deletes all saleItems (1,2,3) and sale from 'sale' table that has id 2.

Comment: I have 'sale' and 'sale_item' tables as you see. 
                          Cascade types 'ALL' in mappings.
                                    When I save sale, it saves sale_items as I want.
            But when I want to delete specific sale_item, it deletes all saleItems which have same sale_id and , related sale.
                      For example in sale table I have a sale that id = 2 and , in sale_item table I have 3 saleItems that ids are 1,2,3 respectively. When I delete saleItem that id = 1, It automatically deletes all saleItems (1,2,3) and sale from 'sale' table that has id 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `CascadeType.ALL` used in the **SaleItem** entity implies that all operations associated with **SaleItem** are affected. When you use the delete operation, it results in the deletion of every **SaleItem** with the same **sale_id**.

By removing the cascade of sale in the **SaleItem** entity, it signifies that without specifying any cascade type, no cascading operations will be applied to the associated entities when performing operations.

you should change:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "sale_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Sale sale;
```

to:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sale_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Sale sale;
```

for deleting data use this code:

```
Sale sale = repo.findById(saleId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("There is no sale with the id"));

Optional<SaleItem> optionalSaleItem = sale.getSaleItems().stream()
        .filter(saleItem -> saleItem.getProduct().getBarcode().equals(barcode))
        .findFirst();

if (optionalSaleItem.isPresent()) {
    SaleItem theSaleItem = optionalSaleItem.get();
    sale.getSaleItems().remove(theSaleItem); // Remove the saleItem from the sale
    saleItemRepo.delete(theSaleItem); // Delete the saleItem explicitly

    // Save the sale without the deleted saleItem
    repo.save(sale);
} else {
    //show log if saleItem not found
}
```

Comment: I did, But in this case it doesn't delete anything. @Morteza Jalambadani

Comment: i change my answer and add plese see how to remove data.